# Is there a way to make my PHP output be in the form of a table? (it must be in a while nested loop)

Tags: php

Specifically I want a multiplication table based on the user's input. All I need is the table because the output is already correct.
Let's say my input multiplier is 2.

This is my code when attempting to do the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Multiplication Table </title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="#">
Enter Multiplier: <input type="text" name="mult"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="m" value="Multiply">
</form>
<table border="1">
<?php
if(isset($_POST["m"])){
        $mult = 0;
        $x = 1;
        $mulpli = 1;
        $pro = 0;

        $mult=$_POST["mult"];

    while($mulpli <= $mult)
    {
        echo "<tr>". "<th>". " ";
        echo "<th>". $mulpli;
        while($x <= $mult)
        {
            $pro=$x*$mulpli;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>". $x;
            echo "<th>". $pro; 
            $x=$x+1;
        }
        $x = $x-$mult;
        $mulpli=$mulpli+1;
    }
    }
?>
</th></th></tr></th></th></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Table:

[image: table]

My desired output:

[image: My desired output]

Comment: A `<th>` within another one, is that even allowed? Please post the table that you would like to obtain.

Comment: Just edited the body. Thnx for the heads up

Comment: OK and what do the inputs `$_POST['m']` and `$_POST['mult']` represent and what impact should they have on this table?

Comment: I don't have the $_POST ['m'] your talking about but $_POST['mult'] represents the users inputted multiplier. basically what I'm saying is that $mult represents the limit of the table to multiply. Ex: if the user's inputted multiplier is 2 then the table must only display a 2x2 multiplication table. Sorry if my codes are messy im still a beginner in php.

Comment: Your code has `if(isset($_POST["m"]))` :) Guess you meant `if(isset($_POST["mult"]))` then.

Comment: sorry again just edited the form code

Comment: now i think it should make sense regarding the $_POST ['m']

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but with a multiplier of 2 you would get 3 rows and 3 columns right? Should be relative easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. I made use of PHP's [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for cleaner view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Multiplication Table</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
        th, td { text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <label>Enter multiplier limit: <input type="text" name="limit"></label>
    <button type="submit">Show Table</button>
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['limit'])):
    $limit = max(1, (int)$_POST['limit']);
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php for ($x = 0; $x <= $limit; $x++): ?>
            <th scope="col"><?= $x ?: '' ?></th>
            <?php endfor ?>
        </tr>
        <?php for ($y = 1; $y <= $limit; $y++): ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?= $y ?></th>
            <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $limit; $x++): ?>
            <td><?= $y * $x ?></td>
            <?php endfor ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endfor ?>
    </table>
<?php endif ?>

</body>
</html>
```